# Can we have a 'Blog' button on the front page to take visitors directly to the security blog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog

I think anything we can do to make it simpler for both newbies and experienced hands would be a useful addition.

Answer (score 1):

This is accomplished via the footer and the header. There is a link to the blog that will always be available to all users in the footer. In the header, there will be a blog link for all users whenever there is a new post, to help highlight when new posts have been made. As such, if you have an active blog, you'll have a very easy access to it.

You can also take extra measures of your own. You have a [community ad for your blog](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372/community-promotion-ads-2h-2011/408#408) - once it has enough votes, it will turn up in your ad cycle, and is an excellent way to bring even more attention to the blog. ♪

Comment: The red "new" block is really annoying and does not go away after clicking on the link

Comment: @Hendrik The red block shows up only for the first 24 hours. Which, admittedly, yes, is the only time it'll show up in the header. There's a pending Meta Stack Overflow request that's being made to address that, I hear, though.