# Community Promotion Ads - 2H 2011

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1085/community-promotion-ads-2013)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool site-related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- the site's blog
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. This question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/372).

Comment: Should we be having a new thread for 2H 2012 by now, or should this just be edited so that it is not time-specific?

Comment: Uhh yeah, I'm not sure why you don't. I've passed this along to the Community Team.  They should check in soon.

Answer (score 15):

[image: @StackSecurity]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Security News]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Every week, the Security Stack Exchange community selects an interesting question to be highlighted in the Community Blog as the "Question of the Week". Vote now on the next QotW, or submit a question you liked!]

Answer (score 5):

[image: "The quieter you become, the more you are able to hear..."]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Join the DMZ to chat with Sec.SE security nerds today!]

Comment: Needs more freehand circles.

Comment: @ScottPack I <3 mspaint.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I <3 this.