# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

We never really gave you a proper thread this past year, so your previous thread was exceedingly stale for a while. As such, here comes a brand new, shiny thread for y'all! Community Promotion Ads, let's go~

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool web app related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1085).

Answer (score 25):

[image: KeePass Password Storage]

Answer (score 23):

[image: Join us in the DMZ - It's a laugh!]

Comment: I see you're not a fan of the Oxford comma. Plebe.

Comment: @ScottPack I am, but I drew this up in Paint in about 30 seconds ;)

Comment: If your language requires you to write a comma before 'and', you need to change language.

Comment: @medivh It's not a requirement, it's a standard writing style that's considered to be "proper" when writing in English.

Comment: @Polynomial Considered "proper" by the same type of people who think the decision to write prepositions at the ends of sentences is something you can be wrong about.

Answer (score 22):

[image: OWASP - Application Security Is Not Just for Developers]

Answer (score 18):

[image: Wireshark - Go Deep]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Open Source Host-based Intrusion Detection System]

Comment: Well this looks familiar :P

Comment: @LucasKauffman Yeah, I pulled a bunch that seemed appropriate from the SOFU metas - also including OWASP, KeePass, and WireShark.

Answer (score 14):

[image: @StackSecurity]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Security News]

Answer (score 14):

[image: The Quieter you become...]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Crypto Stackexchange]

Comment: @mikeazo Thanks for the heads-up! Maybe this would've been a good question for Crypto.SE itself? I mean, the promo-pic surely would've been a bit more on topic as the usual "can you decypher" questions. #LOL

Comment: @mikeazo Great, that means it makes even more sense that I expected!

Comment: @makerofthings7 Feel free to do so. Now that at least two other people know the solution/plaintext, I surely wouldn't mind if you hide/delete the related comment(s). After all, the initial idea indeed was that people might be puzzled enough to visit Crypto.SE to ask/learn about it (and other crypto-related things). ;)

Answer (score 12):

[image: Security B-Sides]

Comment: What is Security bsides?

Comment: Click on it and you will see - community organised series of conferences worldwide

Answer (score 11):

[image: Unleash the beast!]

Comment: Bit too black hat-ish? The things on his eyes are what criminals wear, and the use of black and blue is also sinister.

Comment: I find that rather discriminating

Comment: While I'd hope any regular of the site would know what Metasploit is, it'd be nice if it was included in the ad somehow.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Every week, the Security Stack Exchange community selects an interesting question to be highlighted in the Community Blog as the "Question of the Week". Vote now on the next QotW, or submit a question you liked!]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Chat with Sec.SE security nerds in your area. Join the DMZ!]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Attrition.org - uncovering security sins since 1999]

Comment: Where can I learn about security there?

Comment: @AndreyBotalov Think of them as an unofficial regulator of the security industry, with a cynical sense of humour. Attrition aims to publish information about members of the information security community that are charlatans, frauds and plagiarists. They're focused on improving the industry by keeping tabs on the people that damage its image. Their [official about page](http://attrition.org/attrition/) has more details.

Comment: Not a fan of this. While I support them, and totally get why you want to push this to more awareness, it does put a bit of a negative spin on the site ads. I'd rather keep it more positive, productive, "upbeat".

Answer (score 3):

[image: What's going on? Help us find out!]

Comment: AsheeshR, the font is **ugly**. This picture needs a more antiquated look.

Comment: @DeerHunter: it's pixelated for a reason. But by all means, go ahead and post a changed version. Find the project files [here](https://bitbucket.org/0xC0000022L/re.se-community-ad) ;) ... btw, I'm the author and *not* a graphics designer.